# Hibernate For input string:

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, hql

I have a probleme to show some values in dataTable

this is the code of dataTable

```
<h:form>  
    <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{competence.getAllCompetence()}">  
    <p:column headerText="Model">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.idCompetence}" />  
        </p:column> 
        </p:dataTable>
```

this is the Query

```
public List<Object> findAllCompetence() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getHibernateTemplate().find("select c,pro from Competence as c  join c.technologies as pro ");
    }
```

and The message Error is

```
Grave: Error Rendering View[/default.xhtml]
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "idCompetence"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:159)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:45)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:173)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:200)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)


Hibernate: select competence0_.idCompetence as idCompet1_3_0_, technologi1_.idTechnologie as idTechno1_7_1_, competence0_.llibelleCompetence as llibelle2_3_0_, competence0_.description as descript3_3_0_, competence0_.niveauExpert as niveauEx4_3_0_, technologi1_.idCompetence as idCompet2_7_1_, technologi1_.libelleTechnologie as libelleT3_7_1_ from gestioncollaborateur.competence competence0_ inner join gestioncollaborateur.technologie technologi1_ on competence0_.idCompetence=technologi1_.idCompetence
```

I dont know what the probleme is i think its related to the return object

Comment: Can you try running the query that is being printed? You might get a clue from that.

Comment: How i run it !!  Hrishikesh

Comment: Um, in your [second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082633/hibernate-left-join-returns-objects) you use another query.

Comment: Run your query which says Hibernate : in your question. Run that directly on your DB, using SQLDeveloper or Toad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a `List<Object>`, which the datatable iterates. Each Object is in fact a `Object[]`, where the first array entry is the `Competence` object and the second entry is the matching `Technologies` entry.

JSF tries to use `"idCompetence"` as an index into the array and fails. That's where your exception comes from. Try `#{car[0].idCompetence}` instead and see if that helps.

Comment: I think you should accept it as an answer if you took @mabi solution :)